# Access Nested Levels of a dict Without Nested Looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.3

I have a dictionary that contains simulation results of various protocols for various values of `n` ("protocols" and `n` are irrelevant to the problem I face). This dictionary is structured as follows:

```
myDict = {"protocol1" : {1:[some list of numbers], 2:[another list of numbers]},
          "protocol2" : {1:[some list of numbers], 2:[another list of numbers]},
         }
```

Now, in order to analyze the results, I would do something like this:

```
for protocol, stats in myDict.items():
  for n, counts in stats.items():
    # do stuff with protocol, n and counts
```

I wonder though, if there exists some set of built-ins that allow me to do this, without having to define a custom iterator:

```
for protocol, n, counts in magicFunc(myDict):
  # do stuff with protocol, n and counts
```

Is there something in `itertools` perhaps, that lets me do this?

Comment: As it stands I'd stick with what you've got. If you second dict, instead of lists having more dicts which had more dicts, then in effect, you'd use a dict flattener and yield from that. Otherwise, any solution for your current problem is going to be more obscure and not worth it...

Comment: `you'd use a dict flattener`. Does such a thing exist (very interested), or do I have to write it myself (less interested)?

Comment: Whipped up a quick example of what I meant.... It might have some value if you get more deeply nested - otherwise - stick with what you got...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's any nicer... I'd stick with what you've got for your example, but were it to become deeper, than something like:

```
myDict = {
    'p1': {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6]},
    'p2': {3: [7, 8, 9], 4: [0, 1, 2]}
}

from collections import Mapping

def go_go_gadget_go(mapping):
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        if isinstance(v, Mapping):
            for ok in go_go_gadget_go(v):
                yield [k] + ok
        else:
            yield [k] + [v]

for protocol, n, counts in go_go_gadget_go(myDict):
    print(protocol, n, counts)

# p2 3 [7, 8, 9]
# p2 4 [0, 1, 2]
# p1 1 [1, 2, 3]
# p1 2 [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Why not `[k, v]` instead of `[k] + [v]`?

Comment: @falsetru that would have been easier than copy pasting and changing `v` to be a list wouldn't it :p

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use `protocol`, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
import itertools
for n, counts in itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, myDict.values())):
    # do stuff with n and counts
```

Comment: But that still implicitly loops twice, right? Granted it may be faster, but there is an implicit look in there.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, Anyway, loop is unavoidable.

Comment: @ChadMiller, The question is changed after I posted the answer.

Comment: I do need to use `protocol`. I've edited my post to reflect that. Sorry about the confusion. @GamesBrainiac: implicit double looping is less of a concern at this point. I want to be able to unroll all levels of nesting without too much effort. So the call to `map(dict.items, myDict.values())` is more concerning, as that doesn't scale very easily to more levels of nesting

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I was thinking just the same, the fastest you could hope for is a list comprehension. I'm working on something right now, and lets see if it works. But the thing is, its going to be hard without a double loop.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: I care less about an implicit double loop and more about having to type `for x,y in someDict.items()` twice

Comment: @inspectorG4dget WIll there only be 2 items inside ever protocol dict? Otherwise, its not possible.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: if you mean "only two levels of nesting", that is true for the problem that I am facing at the moment, but a specific solution to that would not be very generalizable. If you mean "only two keys in `myDict`", that is incorrect